# Setting row-wise constraints in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a model of this type:
        P = M*T + error,
where P is a matrix nxm, M is a matrix nxk and T is a matrix kxm.

I want to find the least square solution to this problem under the constraints that every element of T must be nonnegative and each row of the resulting product M*T must add up to 100.

How can I do this using scipy.optimize.minimize?

Comment: Go for the [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html). This should be quite clear. If not, come back with something more explicit (what did you try? what failed?)

Comment: Well, the thing is that I don't know how to write that constraint in an effective way... how do I say in a python function that each row in M*T must add up to 100?